# How to parse an input line with sscanf?

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, input, scanf

I have an input .txt file that looks like this:

```
Robert Hill 53000 5

Amanda Trapp 89000 3

Jonathan Nguyen 93000 3

Mary Lou Gilley 17000 1 // Note that came contains of 3 parts!

Warren Rexroad 72000 7
```

I need to read those lines and parse them into three different categories: name (which is an array of chars), mileage (int) and years(int).

```
 sscanf(line, "%[^] %d %d ", name, &mileage, &years);
```

This doesn't work very well for me, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem with the current specifier passed to `sscanf` is that it is both ill-formed, and even when fixed it won't do what you want. If you would have used `[^ ]` as the first *conversion specifier*, `sscanf` would try to read as many characters as it can before hitting a space.

If we assume that a name can't contain digits specifying `[^0123456789]` will read the correct data, but it will also include the trailing space after the name, but before the first *mileage* entry. This is however easily solved by replacing the last space with a null-byte in `name`.

To get the number of characters read into `name` we can use the `%n` specifier to denote that we'd `sscanf` to store the number of bytes read into our matching argument; we can later use this value to correctly *"trim"* our buffer.

We should also specify a maximum width of the characters read by `%[^0123456789]` so that it doesn't cause a *buffer-overflow*, this is done by specifying the size of our buffer directly after our `%`.

---

**SAMPLE IMPLEMENTATION**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char const * line = "Mary Lou Gilley 17000 1";

  char     name[255];
  int mileage, years, name_length;

  sscanf(line, "%254[^0123456789]%n %d %d ", name, &name_length, &mileage, &years);

  name[name_length-1] = '\0';

  printf ("data: '%s', %d, %d", name, mileage, years);

  return 0;
}
```

```
data: 'Mary Lou Gilley', 17000, 1
```

Comment: Should check `sscanf()` result.  Should be `"%254[..."` "specifying the size of our buffer" - 1. (size is width + 1)  Suggest "[^0123456789+-]".

Comment: Thank you, your answer worked just great. I just didn't really get why do I need the name_length variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function that finds the positon of the first digit like so:

```
// This function returns the position of the 
// space before the first digit (assuming that
// the names dont contain digits)...
char *digitPos(char *s){
    if isdigit(*(s+1)) return s;
    else return digitPos(s+1);
}
```

You can then just separate the two variables by inserting a `'\0'` at the right position like so:

```
pos  = digitPos(line); // This is a pointer to the space
*pos = '\0';
strcpy(name, line);
sscanf(pos + 1, "%d %d", &mileage, &years);
```

Comment: +1 This is a step in the right direction.  You should take it further, of course, and not use `scanf` at all.

Comment: Also, your `digitPos` needs to check for string terminators.  And C does not guarantee to provide "proper tail recursion", although I expect most modern compilers will do the Right Thing for this example.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get started.  It lacks the intelligence of BLUEPIXY's solution which handles the trailing whitespace a little better than mine ( or you could chop it off yourself).

```
dan@rachel ~ $ echogcc -o t t.c
dan@rachel ~ $ echo "Dan P F 3 21" | ./t
Name:    Dan P F ,
Mileage:         3,
Years:   21.
```

Here's the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
        char *buf;
        int mileage, years;
        while(!feof(stdin) ){
                if( fscanf( stdin, "%m[^0-9] %d %d", &buf, &mileage, &years) == 3 ){
                        fprintf(stderr, "Name:\t %s,\nMileage:\t %d,\nYears:\t %d.\n", 
                                buf, mileage, years
                        );
                }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have discovered one of the three reasons `*scanf` should never be used: it's almost impossible to write a format specification that handles nontrivial input syntax, especially if you have to worry about recovering from *malformed* input.  But there are two even more important reasons:

- Many input specifications, including your `%[...]` construct, are just as happy to overflow buffers as the infamous `gets`.
- Numeric overflow provokes undefined behavior -- the C library is licensed to *crash* just because someone typed too many digits.

The *correct* way to parse lines like these is to scan for the first digit with `strcspn("0123456789", line)`, or `while (*p && !isdigit(*p)) p++;`, then use `strtoul` to convert the numbers that follow.

Answer (score -1):

```
int pos;
sscanf(line, "%*[^0-9]%n", &pos);
line[--pos]=';';
sscanf(line, "%[^;]; %d %d ", name, &mileage, &years);
```